# no tab selected by default

Tags: android, android-tabhost

code is given below, problem is i am not able to remove "Main"  tab from the code, as it just closes the application, and that happens because once main tab is removed it selects "call" tab default activity...
buh i want to have  main view as main activity and call or email or web    tab only work when a user click on them

Java code

```
package com.NVT.android;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class MainTabActivity extends TabActivity{

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.tab_activity_layout);

            Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
            TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
            TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
            Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

            // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Main.class);

            // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("main").setIndicator("Main",
                              res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists_grey))
                          .setContent(intent);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);

            TabHost host=getTabHost();

            host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("one")
                    .setIndicator("Call")
                    .setContent(new Intent(this, CallService.class)));

            host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("two")
                    .setIndicator("Email")
                    .setContent(new Intent(this, EmailService.class)));

            host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("three")
                    .setIndicator("Web")
                    .setContent(new Intent(this, WebService.class)));

        }

    }
```

XML coding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             />
                  <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"></FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.NVT.android"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

            <activity android:name=".Main"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
<!--            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> -->
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainTabActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
              <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>


        <activity android:name=".Courses">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".CampusMap">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".GettingHere">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ILoveNescot">
        </activity>


        <activity android:name=".FurtherEducationCourses">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".HigherEducationCourses">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".EmployersTrainingCourses">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".WebService">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".CallService">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".EmailService">
        </activity>








    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Comment: please post your manifest file!

Comment: i just edited it n its there now

Comment: please show us how you try to remove the main-tab

Comment: by removing (intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Main.class);

            // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("main").setIndicator("Main",
                              res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists_grey))
                          .setContent(intent);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);)  line by line, and i just tried it also by commenting it out as well

Comment: In case i change the Intent Filter in the Manifest file, it wouldn;t gonna load the tab activity, as far as i know, and i tried it earlier with another project it didn;t worked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [How to allow user to Add and Delete Tabs in an android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317808/how-to-allow-user-to-add-and-delete-tabs-in-an-android-application)

Comment: i dont think thats what am looking for tbh